Error in coxph: data set has overlapping intervals for one or more subjects
I am performing a survival analysis in a dataframe where it is possible to have multiple events. I am currently using a andersen gill method to account for multiple events.I keep getting this error while there are no rows where the intervals do overlap. I already revised my data and structured it accordingly. Could someone help me with another option in order to understand the origin of this error.
I revised my data twice and restructured it without benefit, the error persists. I am using a andersen gill method for handling the multiple events and tried to add a minimal time factor to events that occuur at the same time point. This with the thought to define that it is seen as a seperate event at the same time point.
